# Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin error on MacOS when running node or npm commands

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, terminal

When running any node or npm commands on the terminal (such as node -v, npm -v or simply node or npm) I get the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Users/alvarez/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.0/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Users/alvarez/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.0/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

My MacOS version is 10.13.6.

The error appeared after installing node through their website and executing the pkg file given. I tried uninstalling node and reinstalling it with nvm (which is the current version installed) and then I got the above error. The error I had when I had node installed through the pkg file was this similar one:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems node v18 requires macOS 10.15 or higher. Either try to downgrade node version to 17 or upgrade macOS.

Comment: I have macOS 10.15 Catalina with node v16 but this error still appearing. Also tried with node v18 still no luck.